# Java Web service using Apt. Do I need an annotation processor? What is wrong?

Tags: java, web-services, annotations, apt

I have been trying to make a simple web service and have been following  [this tutorial](http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/threeminutes.html) . Unfortunately I am stuck.  Here is what I have done so far:

1) I created this class:

```
package server;

import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService
public class HelloImpl {

  /**
   * @param name
   * @return Say hello to the person.
   */
   public String sayHello(String name) {
     return "Hello, " + name + "!";
   }
}
```

2) I ran:

```
apt HelloImpl.java
```

3) I get this warning:

```
hostName[username:~/Desktop/webtest][534]% apt HelloImpl.java
warning: Annotation types without processors: [javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement, javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType, javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType, javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement]
1 warning
```

The apt command should (according to the tutorial) produce these files:

```
HelloServiceImpl.wsdl
schema1.xsd
classes/server/HelloImpl.class
classes/server/jaxrpc/SayHello.class
classes/server/jaxrpc/SayHelloResponse.class
classes/server/jaxrpc/SayHello.java
classes/server/jaxrpc/SayHelloResponse.java
```

This is what was generated when I called apt:

```
HelloImpl.java (not generated but it is still in the directory)
HelloImpl.class
server/jaxws/SayHello.cass
server/jaxws/SayHell.java
server/jaxws/SayHelloResponse.class
server/jaxws/SayHelloResponse.java
```

(missing:)

```
HelloServiceImpl.wsdl
schema1.xsd
```

(the paths are also slightly different)

I suspect that the warning is being generated and the other files are not being generated because I have "Annotation types without processors:".

I think that the warning indicates that it needs an annotation factory (processor).  I know that you can specify what a factory by:

`enter code here`-cp                  Specify where to find user class files and annotation processor factories

I am just unsure of what factory to specify.  (Or maybe I need to configure something differently).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That 5 year old tutorial might be a bit out of date. [jax-ws](https://jax-ws.dev.java.net/) is the successor to jax-rpc. Though, maybe all you need is to run the [wsgen](http://java.sun.com/webservices/docs/2.0/jaxws/wsgen.html) tool instead of apt.

Take a look here for a mini tutorial [In-process SOAP service server for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792737/in-process-soap-service-server-for-java/1793112#1793112)