# Need a java webservice tutorial and how to make a web service secure

Tags: java, soap, jboss, web-services

I have a web service that is using:

- Java (familiar)
- SOAP (new to me)
- JBOSS (new to me)

The web service is currently unsecure.  My task is to make it secure using https (ssl or tsl).

I am new to web services and web things in general.  In the last week have gone through a tone of literature.  Much of it which I think was not relevant to my project.  I think that I need two things:

- A pretty basic tutorial on web services (java specific)
- A tutorial on making web services secured

Here are some of the tutorials I have gone through already:

### [SO Answer - In-process SOAP service server for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792737/in-process-soap-service-server-for-java/1793112#1793112)

- How to make a web service server.
- Does not have instructions for the client.
- Also does not specify what should happen so I am not certain that I got the propper result when navigating to the URL.

### [An Introductory Tutorial on Web Services, Java and XML](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=27308&seqNum=7)

- Pretty good description of lots of xml things and how messages are passed.  Not certain but this seems more low level than what I need

### [Three Minutes to a Web Service](http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/threeminutes.html)

- Good tutorial but in the second step one of the commands did not work.
- I think that this may be because the tutorial is really old and maybe my jdk is differnt or something like that..

Answer (score 1):

You can check out these frameworks

[Apache axis](http://ws.apache.org/axis/)

[Apache cxf](http://cxf.apache.org/)

Comment: downvote for pointing the asker at axis - the documentation is at best mediocre and the api itself leaves a lot to be desired.

Comment: @Bedwyr: Mind you there is another link to apache cxf! and I said check out so that means you have to see what's suitable for you to have an idea... criticizing is not always good

Comment: @Bedwyr: Yes and this answer was for reference and not misleading the asker.

Comment: Upvote: Nothing wrong in referring design details of a rather mediocre API. You can still learn things.

Answer (score 1):

> The web service is currently unsecure. My task is to make it secure using https (ssl or tsl).

If it's just about (one-way) SSL, then this question doesn't have much to do with web services actually. It's more a web server or app server configuration issue. For JBoss, see [SSLSetup](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/SSLSetup) or, if you are using Apache for the SSL encryption, see [Apache SSL/TLS Encryption](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/ssl/).

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that you need to look at JBoss's documentation for how they handle security.  Maybe this would help:

[Chapter 8. Security on JBoss](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/jboss4guide/r1/html/ch8.chapter.htm)

Comment: Wow, that is one long piece of documentation!  Thanks for the link.