# Sending a file from a java client to a server using wcf method?

Tags: wcf

I want to build a wcf web service so that the client and the server would be able to transfer files between each other. Do you know how I can achieve this? I think I should turn it into a byte array but I have no idea how to do that. The file is also quite big so I must turn on streamed response.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're on the right track.  A quick search of the interwebz yielded this link: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/166763/WCF-Streaming-Upload-Download-Files-Over-HTTP

Your question indicates that you want to send a file from a java client to a WCFd endpoint, but the contents of your question indicate that this should be a bidirectional capability.  If this is the case, then you'll need to implement a service endpoint on your client as well.  As far as that is concerned, I cannot be of much help, but there are resources out there like this SO question: [In-process SOAP service server for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792737/in-process-soap-service-server-for-java)

As far as practical implementation, I would think that using these two links you should be able to produce some code for your server and client.

As far as reading all bytes of a file, in C# you can use: [`File.ReadAllBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes.aspx)  It should work as in the following code:

```
//Read The contents of the file indicated
string fileName = "/path/to/some/file";
//store the binary in a byte array
byte[] buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
//do something with those bytes!
```

Be sure to use the search function in the future:
[image: semi-phenomenal, nearly cosmic powered Stack Overflow search function]